# Is there a way to delimit end points using Hough Lines Detector?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm working on image recognition using `Hough Line Detector`. The problem that I found is that when I print `begin(x1,y1)` and `end(x2,y2)` coordinates of the line I get coordinates position that are very far from the edge of the image. 
For example, my image shape is `640x480` and I get coordinates like `(-1000,900)` and if I try to put a circle using `cv2.circle` it is not displayed because it's outside the image. Is there a way to stop `Hough Line` function at the border of the image?

```
dst = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
lines= cv2.HoughLines(dst, 1, math.pi/180.0, 150, np.array([]), 0, 0)
for i in range(a):
   rho = lines[i][0][0]
   theta = lines[i][0][1]
   a = math.cos(theta)
   b = math.sin(theta)
   x0, y0 = a*rho, b*rho
   pt1 = (int(x0+1000*(-b)), int(y0+1000*(a)))
   pt2 = (int(x0-1000*(-b)), int(y0-1000*(a)))
```

I think that the problem is the multiplication in `pt1` and `pt2` but I don't now how i can avoid this and get begin and end point that correspond to the border of the image.

Comment: You need to apply some high-school level math. Basically you need to calculate intersection of two lines, one returned by `HoughLines` and other representing the edge (e.g. left edge is `x = 0`, right edge in your case `x=639`, etc.) As a first step, make sure you understand what the parameters that `HoughLines` returns represent (pen and [graph] paper might come in handy) and what exactly the various calculations in the code do (and why). I have a feeling that may be the root of your problem. There are many references on the net.

Comment: @DanMašek That's exactly the way that I was following before writing this post. I ask this question hoping for a more simple solution like some parameter related to HoughLines to automatically perform this type of operations. Thanks for the response

Comment: `HoughLines` just gives you lines, which are infinite. If you want line segments, then you could try `HoughLinesP`.